# remote xml file and uinavigationcontroller, nsurlconnection placement

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

Firstly, I studied apple's sample codes : SeismicXML and TopSongs but both of them and other tutorials generally calls `NSURLConnection` in app delegate.

In my ugly project, I have to call `NSURLConnection` after user reach some viewcontroller in uinavigationcontroller.

So, I'm asking this design issue, Should I still keep `NSURLConnection` methods in app delegate, and calling from my internet aware vc or completely move this `NSURLConnection` methods and delegates to my internet aware vc ?

Also, there is another design issues which mess my head since I'm not even starter :)

I have to keep the number of view uitableview which is constructed from xml, and its
detailed view. Therefore, I think that I must two request to my web service. One to getting xml file and the other one must be made in detailed view to increase view count of related data in web service.

But, I think that it's not a good solution, Is there any library or any other approach to keep this list and its detailed view counts and notify my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is make a separate class that I use only for connection calls and methods, instantiate it from the delegate, set that instance from the delegate as a property (or manually create its setters and getters) and use in in any class/controller I want to.

This way you modularize your application and the classes don't get tangled up and it's easier to debug/follow the flow of the application.

Comment: Your approach sounds good, but is it good thing call instances from app delegate ? Thanks danipralea.

Comment: Well it may sound a bit childish, but I like to make comparisons for better understanding. For example, the app delegate is the boss in a company, and it "tells" - sends messages to the employees (classes). Sure it is to call instances from the delegate, it's just a class like the others. The order in which you call them and the logic behind it is the one that matters - for example - in this case - you should not have more than one instance of this connection class more than once. Think at it as "global".